# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\Projects\eLearning\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.js'

Tags: jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "shell": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/shell",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",           
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ],
            "es5BrowserSupport": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "shell:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "shell:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "shell:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "shell-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "shell:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "shell:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "shell"
}
```

Comment: Check whether jquery exist in your node nodules

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know what you really want but a command like `npm update` should do the trick.
also if you are making a deployment with `ng build --prod` try to find wheres your dist but this is not the case.
also update angular up to 7/8 and node to 10/12
if not try to `npm install`

Comment: ng build --prod
92% additional asset processing scripts-webpack-pluginAn unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\Projects\eLearning\shell\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.min.js'
See "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-YVSyWl\angular-errors.log" for further details.

Comment: run before commands like npm update or npm install because this is a problem related due to `compilation context`, you hace some problems in some ngModules which are the providers of Compilation context. Try without `--prod` flag because if you havent specify an enviromment will only minimize the dist.

Comment: it looks like a `nodeModules` problem, tell me what happen when you run `npm install` and them `npm update`.

Comment: First: Install jQuery
`npm install jquery --save`
Then: Install jQuery TypeScript autocomplete
`npm install @types/jquery --save-dev`
Finally: Go to the ./angular-cli.json file at the root of your Angular CLI project folder, and find the scripts: [] property, add this inside it:


"../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
After that, jQuery will be available for you as a global variable. You can log jQuery’s version (which is available as jQuery.fn.jquery) to ensure it’s working brilliantly. [source](https://www.gurustop.net/blog/2016/11/18/3821/jquery-angular2-angularcli-how-to)

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to use jquery,

```
npm install jquery --save
```

if you dont really need jquery, get rid of jquery by removing it from the scripts section in the json file.

```
"scripts": [
   "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", <-- remove this
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
],
```